# VBA Dragging down formulas (in multiple rows) to last row used

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have formulas from columns O -> X and need them drag them to last row used. Below is the current code I am using:

```
Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim wkbFrom As Workbook
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim path As String, FilePart As String
Dim TheFile
Dim loc As String
Dim Lastrow As Long

Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
loc = shPivot.Range("E11").Value
path = shPivot.Range("E12").Value
FilePart = Trim(shPivot.Range("E13").Value)
TheFile = Dir(path & "*" & FilePart & ".xls")
Set wkbFrom = Workbooks.Open(loc & path & TheFile & FilePart)
Set wks = wkbFrom.Sheets("SUPPLIER_01_00028257_KIK CUSTOM")
Set rng = wks.Range("A2:N500")

'Copies range from report generated to share drive and pastes into the current week tab of open order report
rng.Copy wkb.Sheets("Current Week").Range("A4")

With ActiveSheet

    Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("O4:X4").AutoFill .Range("O4:X4").Resize(Lastrow)

End With
```

The code Lastrow is not dragging the formulas down

Comment: is it because `.Resize(Lastrow)` actually is spelled `.Reize(Lastrow)` at the bottom of your code?

Comment: Yeah I caught that mistake and fixed it. It is not the problem.

Comment: try recording a macro and manually doing what needs to be done and then modifying the code.

Comment: Once that was fixed it worked for me. Keep in mind that your `Lastrow` reference in `Resize(Lastrow)` is a relative reference. if your last row if 10 then your range will resize 10 more rows to the 14th row.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do auto-fill like this in VBA (verified using macro recording)

```
Range("O1:X1").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("O1:X25"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Now that you have this code as a base to work with you can use any variables you like in the syntax like this:

```
Range("O1:X1").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("O1:X" & Lastrow), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Comment: Thank you, one question, I am a little confused as to where I would implement this within my code.

Comment: @kmiao91 you are trying to drag the formulas from cells down to other cells using the auto-fill box on the bottom-right corner of the cell right?

Comment: Correct, but the formulas are located from columns O -> X and I need to drag the formulas down to last row with data in Column A.

Comment: @kmiao91 then if I'm understanding you correctly all you need to do is use the 2nd block of code I showed you in my answer. `Range("O1:X1").Select

Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("O1:X" & Lastrow), Type:=xlFillDefault`

Comment: @kmiao91 edited the ranges in my answer to be specific to your question

Comment: Only problem I have is it doesn't stop at the Lastrow

Comment: you need to set `Lastrow` in your code, currently it seems to be used wrongly. set it like this `Lastrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count`. If you're `Lastrow` variable is wrong then it won't work. In order for my code above to work for you, `Lastrow` must be set to an integer or long and have a number stored in it (representing the last row of data in Column A)

Comment: @kmiao91, forgot to include a tag for above post.

Comment: This should be one line: `Range("O1:X1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("O1:X" & Lastrow), Type:=xlFillDefault`

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

```
Sub sum_1to10_fill()
Sheets("13").Activate
Range("EG12").Copy
Range("EG12:FT36").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
```

End sub

...and filled up my whole label both down and right.